# Adding text to the html code in real time according to a check button is possible?

Tags: php, javascript

well here is the thing, i have this print using php:

```
echo '<a href="'.$npeurl.'"><img src="css/img/confaceEN.png" alt="Access with Facebook"></a>';
```

The `$npeurl` var is generated when the page is load, using the facebook API and is something like this:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=111222333444&amp;redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Finfoabout.me%2FISS%2Ftest.php%3Fclient%3Dzara&amp;state=607a11c13ddb4cc4e5f6af8458cc0f65&amp;scope=email%2C+user_birthday&amp;display=page"><img src="css/img/confaceEN.png" alt="Access with Facebook"></a>
```

The problem is that in the page there is a check button that by default is unchecked, but if the user checks it, i need to add a parameter to the redirect_uri property, something like: `&noemail=1`

What do you think? is this possible using javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.checkbox').toggle(function() {
    var href = $('.link').attr('href');
    $('.link').attr('href', href + '&noemail=1');
}, function() {
    var href = $('.link').attr('href').replace('&noemail=1', '');
    $('.link').attr('href', href);
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It helps, but partially, if you look closely i cant add the new parameter directly into the end of href, i need to add it on redirect_uri that inside the href but somewhere in the middle, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is.
You would do something like:

```
$('input[type=checkbox][class=SOMETHING]').on('click', function() {
    var link = $('a.something');
    link.attr('src', link.attr('src') + '&noemail=1');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible with Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

set an id to your  tag, get it's href attribute (jQuery?), decode the URL in href, strip redirect_uri param, append your property and build the URL again.. well, I'd do it like that, with JS.